# Adding layer outputs with a shape mismatch

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a V-Net, as described by [Milletari et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04797), wherein `Add` layers need to be included. However, as the shape of the tensor from the `Input` layer is modified in the following `Conv3D` layer, the `Add` layer reports a `ValueError` as the shapes of the output tensors no longer match. `Add` requires these shapes to be the same.

In my case:

```py
ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3, 87, 512, 512) (16, 87, 512, 512)
```

Unfortunately, the `Add` layer has a generic enough term that online searches do not return relevant hits.

Example code:

```py
# Assume imports are present

# Down Block 1
input_layer = Input(input_shape)
conv_1_1 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5, 5), padding="same")(input_layer)
prelu_1_1 = PReLU()(conv_1_1)
add_1_1 = Add()([input_layer, prelu_1_1])
conv_1_2 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2)(add_1_1)
prelu_1_2 = PReLU()(conv_1_2)

# Down Block 2
# ...
```

`keras.backend.tile` is applied to the wrong dimension, and `keras.backend.expand_dims` only adds additional axes, not grow one. `keras.layers.Reshape` fails, as the new shape does not have the same amount of elements. A `Concatenate` layer could work, however, the article on V-Nets explicitly calls for an element-wise sum.

Other users have opted for the use of the `merge()` function, however, this function has been deprecated.

I would like to find a way to either grow the `input_layer` tensor to match the shape of the `prelu_1_1` layer, or to find a function that lets me sum mismatched tensors.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any source code from the mentioned article, and all implementations that I have found seem to not clearly address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/merge/):

> It takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape).

The shape of outputs of both `input` and `prelu` layer must be same. After applying `conv` on `input` the shape might have changed and that is why both layers can not be added together.

Comment: Yes. I mention this in my question. I'll edit for extra clarity, though